# Dealing with Password Prompt with Rsync from Java

Tags: java, ssh, rsync

I'm using rsync from a java process (using java.lang.Runtime).  We're using keyless ssh to get around needing a password.

What I would like to do is to disable the password prompt completely -- basically allowing only keyless ssh.  In my java program, if I try to connect to a host that isn't set up correctly for keyless ssh, the whole program freezes because its waiting for the user to enter a password.

Is there a flag or something I can pass to rsync to do this?   Or somehow killing an rsync process from Java that is waiting at the prompt?

(The eternal newbie suggested a server side solution.  Ideally I'd like to keep it client side)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should disable password authentication on the server in this case.

On the server you should add

```
Match User rsyncuser
PasswordAuthentication no
```

to the sshd_config file. (that file can be located in different places depending the system you are logging into. but most likely in /etc/sshd/sshd_config